# Aggregate character variables

Tags: r, character, aggregate

I have the following structure for my database:

```
ZIP Category
1   Rouge
1   Vert
1   Rouge
2   Violet
2   Rouge
2   Noir
3   Vert
3   Violet
4   Rose
```

From it, I want to create the following database

```
ZIP Category               Times
1   Rouge,vert,rouge         3
2   Violet,rouge,noir        3
3   Vert,violet              2
4   rose                     1
```

I tried with the aggregate function:

```
attach(data)
aggdata <-aggregate(category, by=list(zip), FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The `toString()` function is probably needed here:

```
attach(dat)
aggregate(Category, by=list(ZIP), FUN=toString, na.rm=TRUE)
```

> ```
>   Group.1                   x
> 1       1  Rouge, Vert, Rouge
> 2       2 Violet, Rouge, Noir
> 3       3        Vert, Violet
> 4       4                Rose
> ```

Please, note that R is case-dependent.

However, my preferred approach is to use `data.table` for multiple aggregations.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, .(Category = toString(Category), Times = .N), by = ZIP]
```

> ```
>    ZIP            Category Times
> 1:   1  Rouge, Vert, Rouge     3
> 2:   2 Violet, Rouge, Noir     3
> 3:   3        Vert, Violet     2
> 4:   4                Rose     1
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread(
  "ZIP Category
1   Rouge
1   Vert
1   Rouge
2   Violet
2   Rouge
2   Noir
3   Vert
3   Violet
4   Rose"
)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works perfectly with data.table!